# IntelliJ test fails

Tags: java, testing, assertion

Hi I'm trying to test my Calculator.java class with a test case but I get this error :

**java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<3> but was:main.Calculator@5bb21b69
Expected :3
Actual   :main.Calculator@5bb21b69**

This is the test case I wrote

```
public class CalculatorTest {
    @Test
    public void testCalculator(){
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        calculator.calculate(5,2,'-');
        Assert.assertEquals(3,calculator);

    }
```

And this is my calculator class

```
package main;

public class Calculator {



    public Double calculate(double first, double second, char operator) {
        double result;

        switch (operator) {
        case '+':
            result = first + second;
            break;

        case '-':
            result = first - second;
            break;

        case '*':
            result = first * second;
            break;

        case '/':
            result = first / second;
            break;

        // operator doesn't match any case constant (+, -, *, /)
        default:
            System.out.printf("Error! operator is not correct");
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compare a number with a `calculator` object?

Comment: You probably want to be comparing `3` against the value returned by `calculate`. It'll get interesting once you start trying to compare non-integer values.

Comment: I see know... what an easy problem. Thanks

Comment: @Oğuz It's not as easy as you may seem. Comparison of floating point numbers is a rather complicated topic. And another one question: why do you use a Double wrapper as return type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

- Wrong actual value
- Wrong double comparison in case of floating points

  ```
   Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
   double value = calculator.calculate(5,2,'-'); // use result from calculation
   Assert.assertTrue(Math.abs(3 - value) <= 0.000001);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CalculatorTest {
    
    @Test
    public void testCalculator() {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        double actual = calculator.calculate(5, 2, '-');
        Assert.assertEquals(3.0, actual);
    }
}
```

And this test will fall because you divide doubles, not integers.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assert that the result of your test, `3`, is equal to a your `calculator` object. You want the second argument of the assert to be the calculated *value*, not the `calculator` object.

Comment: Yes I just recognized that I was studying for hours. Thanks :)